# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10))??? What does this mean in this context?

Tags: c++

I am building a genetic algorithm and I am having a problem. Is it a problem with memory, I am still new to new and malloc stuff would I need to use it? I would be grateful if someone could explain the error please. After the 4th increment of K I get an error with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)). It gets stuck at

> tmp.at(0) = it_1->first;

```
void Population::Poppairing(int j)
{
int rand_num = 0;
int rand_per = 0;
for (unsigned long i = select.size(); i-=2;)
{
    rand_per = rand()%100;
    if(j < rand_per)
    {
        auto temp_1 = parents.at(select.at(i)).get_genome();//auto here is unordered map
        auto temp_2 = parents.at(select.at(i-1)).get_genome();
        auto it_1 = temp_1.begin();//here it is and iterator
        auto it_2 = temp_2.begin();
        for(int k = 0;k < no_rule; k++)
        {
            rand_num = rand() % no_in;
            advance(it_1,k);
            advance(it_2,k);
            vector<string > tmp(2);
            for(int l = 2; l--;)
            {
                tmp.at(0) = it_1->first;//father 
                tmp.at(1) = it_2->first;//mother
                tmp.at(l).erase((tmp.at(l).begin()+rand_num),tmp.at(l).end());
                tmp.at((!l)).erase(tmp.at((!l)).begin(),(tmp.at((!l)).end()-((tmp.at(!l)).size()-rand_num)));
                children.at(i-l).set_input_pos((tmp.at(l)+tmp.at(!l)),k);
                children.at(i-l).set_output_pos((unsigned char)(parents.at(i-l).get_genome().begin()->second),k);
            }
            tmp.clear();
        }
        children.at(i).re_initialising_map();
        children.at(i-1).re_initialising_map();
    }
    else
    {
        children.at(i) = parents.at(select.at(i));
        children.at(i-1) = parents.at(select.at(i-1));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `select.at(i)` looks wrong if `i` is equal to `select.size()`. The last index you can address is `i-1`. Otherwise, the debugger is your friend - you need to run this under debug, and catch the call stack.

Comment: Spare yourself the trouble and sprinkle some named variables in your code. In six months `tmp.at(l).erase((tmp.at(l).begin()+rand_num),tmp.at(l).end());` will be unreadable to you as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller I understand, but I am just lazy and I don't think i will need it later.

Comment: @RomanK ya, which should be 0?

Comment: Do you really mean the third loop to be `for(int l = 2; l--;)`? What is the stopping condition?

Comment: How about needing it now for debugging? Not so easy with a chained call.

Comment: The stop condition for that would be when it reaches 0.

Comment: @StoryTeller Lol, true, I have been thinking to re write most of the stuff, but ya. Going to try tonight, If I can't find the solution then I will change it, to which its easier for me to read as well.

Comment: "I am still new to `new` and `malloc` stuff" - neither one of them appears in your code!!!

Comment: What is `select`? It has a size method - is it a vector?

Comment: @barakmanos I understand sorry, I meant to say would I need to use new or malloc. I am changing `i` to be reading exactly between 0-9.

Comment: @doctorlove Yes it is a vector of type int.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it seems there was a problem in using `advance` from `iterator` `stl`. Just incremented the it_1 and 2 at the end of k for loop.